# How to divide 1 mongoDB collection into 2 or more collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongoDB to scrap a dataset using Node.js. The collection which I have has 0.2 million documents and so the Node.js is crashing giving a segmentation fault. Is there a way to split/divide the collection to 2 or more collections so that Node.js doesn't crash.
Thanks!!

Comment: mongo should easily host 0.2 million docs. that shouldnt be a problem and really i dont think you should be breaking your collection. have you tried implementing shards ?

Comment: @satishchennupati MongoDB is working fine. Node.js is crashing.

Comment: you can use pagination in your nodejs application to bring limited data and on next move bring more data. can be achieved by limit and skip.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using limit to constraint the no of documents returned? You can take the total document count in collection and then split it using limit and skip For ex: if collection has 200 docs
First time limit 100 docs and skip 0
Second time limit 100 again but this time skip 100
This is oneway i an think of. There may be other ways

Comment: OK I'll try that...Thanks!! :)